# Example for sp_runtime::offchain::storage::mutate()

Tags: offchain-storage

I could not find any example code that shows how to call `mutate()` for offchain storage. Looking for an example. I could only find onchain examples.

https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/offchain/storage/struct.StorageValueRef.html#method.mutate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/examples/offchain-worker/src/lib.rs

```rust
    let val = StorageValueRef::persistent(b"example_ocw::last_send");
    // The Local Storage is persisted and shared between runs of the offchain workers,
    // and offchain workers may run concurrently. We can use the `mutate` function, to
    // write a storage entry in an atomic fashion. Under the hood it uses `compare_and_set`
    // low-level method of local storage API, which means that only one worker
    // will be able to "acquire a lock" and send a transaction if multiple workers
    // happen to be executed concurrently.
    let res = val.mutate(|last_send: Result<Option<T::BlockNumber>, StorageRetrievalError>| {
        match last_send {
            // If we already have a value in storage and the block number is recent enough
            // we avoid sending another transaction at this time.
            Ok(Some(block)) if block_number < block + T::GracePeriod::get() =>
                Err(RECENTLY_SENT),
            // In every other case we attempt to acquire the lock and send a transaction.
            _ => Ok(block_number),
        }
    });
```